# Galera Cluster - Autocommit

Tags: mariadb, autocommit, galera

I set up a galera cluster with 2 nodes, and I disable autocommit at 2servers.

```
   set autocommit=0;
```

INSERT data at server1 and COMMIT,but server2 didn't renew data;

server2 need COMMIT; before SELECT;

how do i  renew data without COMMIT, except  autocommit=1?

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to "critical read" issues, not `autocommit`.  See the manual on `wsrep_sync_wait`, which should be `SET` to 1 before a `SELECT` that *might* be reading data from a node other than the one where the data was written.  This makes sure the replication is caught up so that you get the 'right' answer.

[My Galera blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera#critical_reads) discusses that aspect, and more.

If you need something than a `SELECT` to wait, then use, say, 15 for the value in the `SET`.

(I prefer to explicitly use `BEGIN` instead of using `autocommit=0`; then I can pair up the `BEGINs` and `COMMITs` in code and not leave a transaction 'open' forever.)